# How can I read the name and other information of my handy / mobile phone connected to my PC over usb?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How I can read the name and other information of my Handy / mobile phone connected to my PC on USB in Visual Basic 2010 and give it out on a text field, label or a list field in a Visual Basic 2010 form?

Comment: Hi Luanone, welcome to SO, do read our [on topic guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), at SO, we try to focus on technical difficulties and your question will primarily generate opinionated answers. If you need help starting off, perhaps Quora may be a better choice.

Comment: You should state which operating system the mobile phone can have. I think this does matter.